# Long delay before app start

Tags: android, delay, startup

When I try to start my app it takes like 2 seconds until the splashscreen appears. The "loading screen" before the splashscreen activity is transparent because i have choosen a transparent theme. I already deleted every piece of code in the splashscreen activity but the delay is still up to 2 seconds. Can somebody help me to reduce this time?

Comment: does the delay appears only for the first time after install or everytime?

Comment: @SarthakMittal the delay occours every time i click on the app icon -> then i have to wait for 2 seconds and the the splashscreen appears. I think that a delay that long isnt normal?

Comment: are you using Instant Run for running the application ?

Comment: @RakshitNawani yeah I use it and I have the feeling that the app start hast a way smaller delay when i launch it from android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) takes some time to load. The blank/white screen will go away in production builds.

I'm not sure why Instant Run takes so long to load. If you look in the app's internal cache directory you will see quite a few dex files. There was an article about how Instant Run works posted a couple days ago here: https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f#.ntl30mbe2

You can disable Instant Run from Settings (Ctrl+Alt+s) and just be aware that your production builds will not have this blank white screen.

Comment: Thnak you very much, I wasn't aware that this affects the app in such an way.

Comment: and if you are sending a build for testing send it with disabling the Instant Run, it will crash many times on HTC devices when app is started.

Answer (score 2):

Clean and re build. 
Although, this wont happen in the release build.